# How to create file chooser using Xamarin in WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a mobile application using Xamarin forms, As part of my implementation, I have a requirement to to show file chooser on clicking on camera icon which is loaded in webView. I have seen several samples for the same, but all those samples and examples in stack is written in native code for Android . Is that possible to do it using Xamarin forms alone? It would be good, if a get a proper sample also for the same.

Comment: You may consider using a custom renderer just like Customize WebView and define a method  inside. For details, you may refer to “https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278452/xamarin-webview-call-the-file-chooser-dialog”.

Comment: @HongxinSui - the shared sample explains only to take files from gallery.   As per requirement, I  have to show chooser , where options for camera and file to be shown .